# Получение состояний класса не используя геттеры\сеттеры

Tags: c++, шаблоны-проектирования

Есть некий класс, например для работы с COM портом. У этого класса есть настройки, такие как baudrate, stopbits и прочие. Необходимо получать эти значения. Дело в том что этот класс имеет целую кучу состояний и, как в следствии, огромное кол-во гетеров и сетеров(штук 80). При разработке у меня встал следующий вопрос: Существует ли какой-нибудь способ  (шаблон проектирование например) уменьшить кол-во этих самих геттеров\сеттеров?

Comment: Именованные свойства: `port.setOption("baudrate", 12345);`. Можно использовать enum вместо строк, если хочется run-time проверок на существование такого свойства.

Comment: @Chorkov и интересное решение. Если использовать енумы, то это abi совместимо?

Comment: Сложить все в одну жирную структуру, и сделать для нее геттер.

Comment: А есть какой-то инвариант, который надо поддерживать? Или геттеры/сеттеры просто дают прямой доступ к членам? Тогда они просто не нужны, сделать структуру.

Comment: например в библиотеке boost(asio serial port) есть метод set_option, который принимает в качестве аргумента BoostOptionable. В него можно пихнуть все что угодно, любой тип данных. Оч удобно. Но пока не понятно как он работает